# misspelling javascript function alert to alerler('hell'); and firebug doesn't report an error?

Tags: javascript, firebug

misspelling javascript function alert to alerler('hell'); and firebug doesn't report an error.

Why is that?  It is enabled for localhost (or my site).

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you mean you have a `<script>` that has a call to `alerler` somewhere, right? Well, Firebug only catches errors for code that gets run. ;) So if the code with the misspelled function isn't actually *run* after the page loads, Firebug won't catch the error. This is the only reason I can think of as to why Firebug didn't catch your error.

Answer (score 2):

Works On My Machine<sup>TM</sup>, or should I say Doesn't Work On My Machine<sup>TM</sup>

```
>>> alerler('test');
ReferenceError: alerler is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your FireFox Error Console (Ctrl+Shift+J) could help you on that

Answer (score 0):

Firebug has some weird quirks sometimes like if you setup a debugger; and refresh the page without stopping the debugger, firebug well no longer work properly. Sometimes you get lucky and don't have to restart the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is *very* unlikely, could you have defined a function?

```
function alerler(text) {
    // this is a possibility!
}
```

Though, I would say [musicfreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973272/misspelling-javascript-function-alert-to-alerlerhell-and-firebug-doesnt-rep/973289#973289) has the most probable reason.